# How to set yAxis min/max in Highcharts synchronized chart with JSON

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working with the synchronised chart of Highchart. Pretty cool. However, I would like to »dictate« the min and max values for the yAxis. I added these two parameters into the JSON file, but they are not being accepted unfortunately.

JSON file:

```
    "unit": "km/h",
    "type": "line",
    "min": -2,
    "max": 16,
```

yAxis definition:

```
     yAxis: {
        title: {
           text: null
        },
        min: dataset.min,
        max: dataset.max
     },
```

but that doesn't work. Any idea why? [Here is the](https://graphs-test.unepgrid.ch/graph_global_atmosphere_800000_3.php) original graphic I am working with. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/g8vr2hxz/5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharts API we can read:

> **max: number, null**
>
> ...
>
> If the endOnTick option is true, the max value might be rounded up. (...)

As a solution disable `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` options or use `tickPositioner` function to calculate and set tick postion manually, for example:

```
            yAxis: {
                ...,
                tickPositioner: function(){
                    var ticks = [],
                    step = (dataset.max - dataset.min) / 4;

                  for (var i = dataset.min; i <= dataset.max; i += step) {
                    ticks.push(i);
                  }

                  return ticks;
                }
            }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ev5hz0pk/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Great. Thanks so much! Just a small thing: It should be »enable StartOnTick and endOnTick« and not »disable«.